# Using Homebrew PostgreSQL can't connect to server

Tags: postgresql, homebrew, macos-mojave

My environment

> macOS Mojave 10.14.6 
>   Homebrew 2.1.11 
>   PostgreSQL 11.5

I typed brew command and checked PostgreSQL server is running.

```
brew services start postgresql
```

But I can't connect PostgreSQL server like this command. And it displayed these errors.

```
psql postgres
```

> psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
>       Is the server running locally and accepting
>       connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

How can I solve this problem?

I've already tried to restart PostgreSQL server

```
brew services restart postgresql
```

And also tried this answer, but this file did not exist in the directory.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18832331/5062103

Answer (score 6):

I solved this problem as below.

First, run the database.

```
postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres
2019-09-01 03:27:51.272 JST [5002] FATAL:  database files are incompatible with server
2019-09-01 03:27:51.272 JST [5002] DETAIL:  The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 9.6, which is not compatible with this version 11.5.
```

It displayed **incompatible version** errors.

Second, remove the old database.

```
rm -rf /usr/local/var/postgres
```

Third, initialize new one.

```
initdb /usr/local/var/postgres -E utf8
```